# Yii session expire too fast

Tags: php, session, yii

In my app I set session variable like this:

```
Yii::app()->session['id'] = $user->id;
```

But after some hours its expire.
I tried to set session.gc_maxlifetime to 31536000 but its doesnt help.
How I may increase session time?
Its yii 1 version.